# Gradle flavors for android with custom source sets - what should the gradle files look like?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, source-sets

I've got an old eclipse project I've moved into android studio and setup to use flavors.  It seemed to be working fine till I started trying to use different java files between my flavors.

My project setup is this:

```
ProjectRoot
+- acitonbarsherlock
+- facebook
+- myLib1
+- myProject
   +- src
      +- commonFiles
         +- flavor1
         +- flavor2
   +- res
      +- flavor1
      +- flavor2
```

The innards of the myProject gradle file android closure looks like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

signingConfigs {
     ...
}

productFlavors {
    flavor2 {
    }
    flavor1 {
    }
}

sourceSets{
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    flavor2 {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest-flavor2.xml'
        res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor2', 'res']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java','src/commonFiles/java']
    }

    flavor1 {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor1','res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

}

With my setup like this gradle complains about not being able to find classes I'm trying to inherit from commonFiles in flavor1 or flavor2.

From the various other topics I've looked at on here I see others not even defining source sets, and I feel like what I'm doing in them is perhaps too much.

Has anyone experimented with this before and know how this should properly be configured?

Comment: I don't know if it will help anyone but I used flavorDimensions and it works like magic

Comment: android flavors demo http://goo.gl/5NSnEM

Comment: @nitesh : your demo is for Gradle defined structure, not for custom sourceset that you get when you export Eclipse project as gradle .

Comment: @Akshat this demo is to support the answer of Saad Farooq which is marked as correct.

Comment: For anyone looking at this for android projects: The `sourceSets{...}` part has to be within `android{...}`!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think you'd be better off not defining custom `sourceSets` but using the default gradle configuration. I used to do custom sourcesets until I realized the conventions are, well, convenient.

You'll want something like this:

```
+ src
    + main // this is your common code
        + java 
        + res
    + flavor1
        + java
        + res
    + flavor2
        + java
        + res
```

Then you can just go ahead and remove the sourcesets closure from your `build.gradle`

**NOTE:** For the `gradle` configuration, resources are merged or overridden whereas all `java` code is put on the same class-path. For example, the `AndroidManifest.xml` files for each flavor need only have the differences from `main`'s manifest file. Having an asset, for example, `ic_launcher` in a flavor overrides the `ic_launcher` from main if such file exists. However, having a file `HomeActivity.java` in both `main` and the flavor is not possible and will give a duplicate file error.

Comment: Can you expound on why your answer is following convention? From my understanding, Gradle has incorporated a _convention_ of product flavors and source sets. To me, your answer seems like a ton of duplicated code.

Comment: I added a note to the answer. In fact, code duplication is not possible with this setup.

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks that better helps me understand, very convenient indeed.

Comment: Yup... and actually there was some debate about whether java files in the flavors should override java files in main, for example, if you are making an app where only the `HomeActivity` is different from the flavor, you could just write one file and be done with it. As it stands there are other ways to get around that problem that might be addressed somewhere on SO if you are interested.

Comment: How this is gonna work if I want to have specific dependencies for different flavors. I mean we still end up having a single `gradle` file

Answer (score 46):

You are welcome to use the custom `sourceSets` and `flavours` (or `buildTypes`) if you wish.

As an example, you can set them in your Gradle file as follows:-

```
productFlavors {
    flavor2 {
    }
    flavor1 {
    }
}

sourceSets{
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
  flavor1 {
       java.srcDirs = ['src-flavor1'] 
       res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor1']
       ...
    }

}
```

Comment: How would I do this dynamically? I have sourceSets.whenObjectAdded { sourceSet -> sourceSet.java.srcDirs = "someDir"} and then the source sets defined per flavor like this: sourceSets { flavor1{} flavor2{}}. I want to do something like: sourceSet.debug.java.srcDirs = "someDir" for each product flavor and per buildType.

Answer (score 8):

Here is what my Gradle looks like :

```
   productFlavors {
    // Still keeping the productFlavors closure in case we decide to add flavors later
    normal {
        applicationId 'com.akshat'
    }
    qa {
        applicationId 'com.akshat.qa'
    }
}

 sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jni.srcDirs = [] // Set empty since we use our own ndkBuild task
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }

    normal {
        java.srcDirs = ['src_normal']
    }
    qa{
        java.srcDirs = ['src_qa']
    }
```

And here is how my Directory structure is :

```
MyApplication
    - res
    - libs
    - jni 
    - src
         -com/akshat/
    - src_qa
         - com/akshat/util/FlavorConst.java
    - src_normal
         - com/akshat/util/FlavorConst.java
```

Answer (score 8):

This way works for me. Enjoy

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['srs/others']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
        }
        development{
            res.srcDirs += ['development/src/res']
        }
        standford{
            res.srcDirs += ['standford/src/res']
        }

        commercial{
            res.srcDirs += ['commercial/src/res']
        }

    }
    productFlavors {
        development{
            flavorDimensions "default"
        }
        standford{
            flavorDimensions "default"
        }
        commercial{
            flavorDimensions "default"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can code like the example below i taking**

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        java.srcDirs = ['src', '../3party/Alohalytics/src/android/java', 'ttsearch/jni/out']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets', 'flavors/mwm-ttf-assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs', 'jniLibs', 'ttsearch/libs']
    }
    flavor {
        manifest.srcFile 'flavor'
        assets.srcDirs = ['flavor/assets']
        res.srcDirs = ['flavor/res']
        res.srcDirs = ['flavor/res']
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Variant with custom sourceSets have an issue. For example,if we want change only several lines for some flavors,we have structure xxx/res-paid/values/strings.xml with two strings,which use in manifest file. in this case we have android linking faild error for manifest file. So variant with custom sources not works,as it must. Maybe i will report issue about it to google and gradle.