# Gradle build failed on Android Studio old and new versions on OSX

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-resources, android-build

I had a successfully building project when I was working on my PC and I committed and pushed it to my Git repo before migrating to OSX.

Now, I installed Android studio latest version on OSX and tried to build the same project and it gives errors in building resources. While building resources in Manifest, it gives multiple errors that say

> No resource found that matches the given name

for drawables and strings.

On looking through web, I thought maybe the newer version of gradle has some issues. So, I downgraded my installation of AS to AS 1.0 and used the old gradle 2.2. Unfortunately, this version of gradle also gives the same error.

My `build.gradle` looks like below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.3"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets {

    main {
        res.srcDirs = [
                "/src/main/res"
        ]
    }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/thermodosdk-1.0.18.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
```

The `build.gradle` at top level has the following classpath:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,     :app:generateDebugTestSources]
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
/Users/vidhigoel/AndroidStudioProjects/OMGAndroid/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(24, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/omg_app_icon').
Error:(25, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(27, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
Error:(30, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(86, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(105, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(123, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(137, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title_activity_register_user').
...
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.462 secs
Information:17 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: can you post your actual errors please, stacktraces if possible.

Comment: please post the error log for easier tracking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need this part in your `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {

    main {
        res.srcDirs = [
                "/src/main/res"
        ]
    }
}
```

1. It is the default value and you do not need to put it there.
2. You have the wrong path. As i said it is the default path and not really required, but if you still want to add it [check this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461145/gradle-flavors-for-android-with-custom-source-sets-what-should-the-gradle-file) to see how to add it correctly.

You might just want to say:

```
res.srcDirs = ['res']
```

Remove the `sourceSets` section from the `build.gradle`. After removing the above mentioned configuration do a clean and rebuild. To be on a safer side also do a `File - > Invalidate Cache and Restart`

Answer (score 1):

Just change your gradle classpath.

Replace

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

**EDIT:**

also need to add older version of you `AppCompact` like below:

```
  dependencies {
...
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
...
}
```

Comment: That `com.android.tools.build:gradle` is in beta and that `appcompat` version is very old.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this link may be help you**
[Installing Gradle In OSX](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/12/installing-gradle-on-osx.html)

**Please also check this one Points**

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.

Since if  you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.

Alternatively you can continue compiling against version 22 of the Android SDK by switching to the latest support library v22.

Comment: I am using version 21 of the support library

Comment: Then compile with 21 versionof sdk

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "Build/Clean Project"?