# Build.gradle flavor sources

Tags: android, gradle

Assuming flavor1a, flavor1b, flavor2a, and flavor2b...

Assuming directory structure:

src

-flavor1

-flavor2

-main

Is there a simple way, in gradle, to do the following:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1a {
        // Point to src/flavor1
    }
}
```

I can't seem to configure via sourceSets = ['src/xxxx'] in each product flavor in my build.gradle

Comment: check out this accepted [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461145/gradle-flavors-for-android-with-custom-source-sets-what-should-the-gradle-file). You'll have to change your directory structure but it seems like a better solution

Comment: The problem is that the only thing that is different between flavors is the applicationId. I don't want to duplicate the folders because it will double the footprint of my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of configuring `sourceSets` within the `productFlavors` block, try:

```
productFlavors{
    flavor1{
    }
    flavor2{
    }
}

sourceSets{
    main{
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main']
        //other typical sourceSets stuff
    }

    flavor1.java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1']
    flavor2.java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2']
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but I didn't have to add a main{} sourceSets only had to add the flavors